# AngularJS - Binding multiple classes in directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm using Waves plugin and I want to use this on 3 different classes.

In jQuery my codes goes like this

```
Waves.attach('.button', ['waves-button', 'waves-float']);
Waves.init();
```

In Angular I have converted this to a directive

```
.directive('waves', function(){
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            link: function(scope, element) {
                Waves.attach('.btn', ['waves-button', 'waves-float']);
                Waves.init();
            }
        }
    })
```

I have many elements with above mentioned classes and in all of them, I have to use an extra attribute to make it work `data-waves`

To avoid this, I've restricted the directive to class but I was able to bind only one class.

```
.directive('btn', function(){
      return {
          restrict: 'C',
          ...
```

How can I bind multiple classes to a single directive when it's restricted to class? I'm expecting some thing like

```
.directive(['class1', 'class2', 'class3'], function(){
      return {
         restrict: 'C',
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that you must create new directive but share the factory function.

```
function mySharedDirectiveFactory () {
  return {
  // directive object
  };
}
angular.module('myModule')
.directive('class1', mySharedDirectiveFactory)
.directive('class2', mySharedDirectiveFactory)
.directive('class3', mySharedDirectiveFactory);
```

Anyway I think that the best is to create just one directive and restrict it to an element or an attribute, so you will have just one definition.